# Outlook item events not firing correctly

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, outlook-addin, office-interop

I have an Outlook add-in, where I have to do some calculation whenever a Task / Appointment Item is changed.

I managed to get the Item.Write, and Item.BeforeDelete events hooked up via an Inspector Wrapper. These are working out pretty great, but it's not enough, since there are more events in Outlook, that can change (or do other things) with an object.

One of the most important events it the Appointment MOVE event, where I drag-n-drop a calendar item in the calendar, and it changes its dates. 
**After further inspection, I found out, that the BeforeItemMoveEventHandler is not really good for this, so I just simply went with the ItemChange event on the Item collection object.**
To implement this, I have a function, that runs on startup, and looks something like this:

```
public Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler ChangeHandler;
public Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler MoveHandler;
public void SetupEventHandlers()
{
    Outlook.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("mapi");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder calendar = null;
    Outlook.Folder calendarFolder = null;
    Outlook.Items appointments = null;
    try
    {
        calendar = OutlookHelper.GetMAPIFolderByName("My Calendar");
        appointments = calendar.Items;
        ChangeHandler = new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(Appointments_ItemChange);
        appointments.ItemChange += ChangeHandler;

        calendarFolder = OutlookHelper.GetOutlookFolderByName("My Calendar");
        MoveHandler = new Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(Appointments_ItemMove);
        calendarFolder.BeforeItemMove += MoveHandler;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //failed to get calendar, and to add the itemchange event;
    }
}
```

I've read in many places, that the events have to be specified as a global variable, in order to not be garbage collected.

Tried it both ways, but the outcome is, that the event gets fired 2-5 times and then it just stops, without any error message.

The 2 subfunctions there (GetMAPIFolderByName and GetOutlookFolderByName) are 100% returning the requested object and type. If they were the source of the problem, then it wouldn't work at all.

**PROBLEM #1**
The Appointments_ItemChange event gets fired when I start up the application. Since I want to have a server-sync kind of thing hooked up to these events, doing a call towards the server with unnecessary data upon startup is not really good. There should be a way to ignore this ItemChange event on startup...?

**PROBLEM #2**
The events are fired randomly! I installed an Outlook Event monitor add-in, that displays what kind of events are fired and when are they called, and sometimes it even fires an ItemChange event after 1 minute. Also, it fires multiple ones (to overcome this, I have a *kind of* solution that you can see in my code example below)

The Appointments_ItemChange function looks like this

```
public Boolean AppointmentThreadRunning = false;
public Thread AppointmentItemChangeThread;
public void Appointments_ItemChange(object Item)
{
    if (!AppointmentThreadRunning) //check if there is a running thread
    {
        AppointmentItemChangeThread = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            AppointmentItemChangeThreadedFunction(Item); //call the thread which will change the value of the boolean and keep it for 3 seconds
        });
        AppointmentItemChangeThread.Start();
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)Item;
        CallSyncAppointmentChange(appt); //call the sync server function
    }
}

public void AppointmentItemChangeThreadedFunction(dynamic OutlookItem)
{
    AppointmentThreadRunning = true;
    //wait 3 seconds, so if Outlook decides to fire another ItemChange it will not call the SYNC 
    Thread.Sleep(3000); 
    AppointmentThreadRunning = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to make the event handler a class variable. I had to make the **appointments** (Outlook.Items type) a global variable as well...